# Conditional replacement using sed?

Tags: sed

I am using `sed` to replace `url(\'test.png\')` with `url(\'/navigation/test.png\')`

This is working fine with this command

```
sed -i "s#url(\\\'#url(\\\'/navigation/#g" "main.js"
```

I would however like to exclude url statements that already start with a `/`
for example `url(\'/favicon.png\')`

Is this possible with `sed`?

Comment: url(\'test.png\') should turn into url(\'/navigation/test.png\')
url(\'/test.png\') should remain url(\'/test.png\')

Answer (score 1):

The key is to provide a little more context in the regular expression:

```
sed -e "s#\\(url(\\\\'\\)\\(test.png\\\\')\\)#\1/navigation/\2#g"
```

Also note that:

- Within doublequotes, `'` is not special.
- Within doublequotes you need to write `\\` to get one `\`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^/]` to match any char but the slash and have `url(\'[^/]` as a pattern in your `s` command. This will of course destroy your first char, so you have to make a subexpression out of it `\([^/]\)`, so you can preserve it as `\1` in the replacement:

```
sed -i "s#url(\\\'\\([^/]\\)#url(\\\'/navigation/\\1#g" "main.js"
```

A different attempt would be to always replace, but revert if there already was a slash:

```
sed -i "s#url(\\\'#url(\\\'/navigation/#g;s#navigation//##g" "main.js"
```