# Replacing contents in a file using sed or PERL

Tags: linux, regular-expression

I would like to run this regular expression https://regex101.com/r/9LJAjZ/1 using sed or perl to replace the contents of a file.

If I am correct this will never work with sed because sed is always greedy. But how can I make this regex work with perl.

This is what I've got so far:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s#url\(\\[\'|\"]((?!data:|\/).*)\\[\'|\"]\)#url\(\\\'/prefix/\1\\\'\)/#g" file.js
```

example input file:

```
url(\'font-awesome.woff\') url(\'bont-awesome.woff\') url(\'/favicon.ico\') url(\'data:whatever\')
```

example output

```
url(\'/prefix/font-awesome.woff\') url(\'/prefix/bont-awesome.woff\') url(\'/favicon.ico\') url(\'data:whatever\')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional replacement using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546284/conditional-replacement-using-sed)

Comment: Greedyness is not a problem if you take care to exclude the closing `)`, for example: `sed -E "s#url\(\\\'(\[^/][^):]*\))#url\(\\\'/prefix/\1#g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your command a bit:

```
$ perl -pe 's#(url\()(\\['\''"])((?!data:|/).*?\2\))#$1$2/prefix/$3#g' foo
url(\'/prefix/font-awesome.woff\') url(\'/prefix/bont-awesome.woff\') url(\'/favicon.ico\') url(\'data:whatever\')
```

The regex, which I put in single quotes as the benefit of using `\'` and `\"` is outweighed by all the additional escaping needed, is:

```
s#(url\()(\\['"])((?!data:|/).*?\2\))#$1$2/prefix/$3#g
   _____  ______  __________________ 
    $1     $2 \2         $3
    url(   \'         ...\')
           \"         ...\")
```

`.*?` is lazy, and in the replacement, groups are referred to using `$1`, `$2`, etc. (unlike in the pattern, where it's `\1`, `\2`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. This works. But I would need it to work with double quotes as I am in a docker container. the "prefix" text is a variable which should be replaced.

perl -pi.bak -e 's#(url\()(\\['\''"])((?!data:|/).*?\2\))#$1$2/${project}-fe/$3#g' file.js

Comment: Found it. What a horrible piece of code ... :)
perl -pi.bak -e "s#(url\\()(\\\\[\\'\\\"])((?!data:|\\/).*?\\2\\))#\$1\$2/${project}-fe/\$3#g" file.js